# How to create a new Server Instance on MySQL Workbench 5.2.25 CE

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've just setup MySQL Workbench 5.2.25 CE on a PC with windows XP service pack 3
When trying to create a new server instance on the localhost, Workbench ask me for a root password regarding the service. I've have not been asked during the setup process to enter a password for root... leaving the password blank (or even inputting a 'fake' password) leads to the folowing error message :

'Connecting to MySQL server localhost...

Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)'

Using a cmd box and trying to log on mySQL as root (mySQL -u root) I have also the following error : ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

The setup of mySQL went fine and I was not asked for anything... did I something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but ...

Take a look at the my.ini file,  If there is a default user/password.  use that.  If this is set mysql will use this.

You can also try 
    mysql -uroot -p

if the password is really blank then this will let you in